# There any limit to the values you can set for post_max_size or upload_max_filesize?

Tags: php

I am tasked with creating an uploader for a site that can handle very large files to avoid the clients having to use ftp as the means to send. By very large I mean upwards to 2 gigs in size. I have researched a few options and tested a couple implementations, one of them is:

http://www.easyflashuploader.com/en/efu-audio-uploader-demo#start

Only problem is this one does no file chunking ( that I know of ) so it requires me setting post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to ridiculous numbers to compensate. Is there a limit to what you can set this up to? Big reasons against doing so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2 Gigs sounds like a bad idea in a file upload... There is no way to resume downloads, for example, which sucks when uploading a 4GB file. Is building a custom FTP/SFTP/WebDAV client  completely out of the question? There may be Java based uploaders that can do this, though

Comment: Java based uploader is out of the question for me to use. They told me to research into flash uploaders and was pointed at that to look at. I did research into the topic and apparently flash in general can choke on huge files once again due to the 32 bit byte size limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's pretty crappy when it comes to large file uploads, particularly because you have to a memory limit higher than the size of the file. As well, Apache on 32bit systems tends to have a 2gig file limit itself, so even if PHP could handle the upload, Apache will choke.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is not designed for sending HUGE amounts in a single request.  And some servers/clients will choke on it. On apache i think the upper limit is 2GB. And if it messes up half way through, then you get to start over.  FTP/SFTP/SCP would be a better tool right tool for the job.

Comment: http://www.plupload.com/ they have a silverlight option which seems to be able to handle very large file uploads via chunking the file and me not having to set any of the server variables to insane amounts. Anyone have experience with this?